# How to check if defined Event exists in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

I've defined an event like this:

```
var event = new Event('myevent');
```

Is there anyway which i can check an event called 'myevent' has been defined ?
I want to have an option like this:

*If an event called 'myevent' exists, attach a handler to it, else attach the handler to another event like 'myevent2' !*

Comment: you don't attach listeners to events, you attach them to event targets. Whether an event targets emits a certain kind of event is a completely different story. And you haven't "defined" or "declared" a new event type, you just instantiated a new event instance in the local scope. It does not affect anything else.

Comment: I agree with Bergi's comments.  Your question implies that maybe you don't understand how custom events work.  I'd suggest you read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: ^^^ agree with those two, but you can check if the variable is defined and if the event type is `myevent` like this `if (event && event.type == 'myevent') ....`

Comment: Ok let me be more specific. I've wrote some kind of a plugin called "resizestop" which triggers when the window resizing has been stopped for some timeout.
now i want to use this in another plugin. you can somehow say that the  newer plugin requires the resizestop plugin. Now i want to check this requirement by checking if the event has been defined.

any suggestion (except copy and paste resizestop code on the top of your new plugin) ?

and btw thank you all for your responces

Comment: @adeneo one idea which pass in my head was to create a global variable  and assign the event to it. but i'm not a big fan of global variables, thats why i asked it here

Comment: Great question .  I found this func getEventListeners but return only {}

Answer (score 1):

This will check if the event variable is and event object

```
if(event instanceof Event)
    //All Good lets go
```

Comment: Actually the event has been created in a function (it has a local scope). but i've never thought of using 'instanceof' keyword, thank you for that ;)